# mediaplayer not stop when change the another view in android

Tags: android, android-layout, media-player, android-view

in my android application I have two views. the one view have mediaplayer.it's playing set of songs from raw folder.the another view is  imageView. Same layout have one button change.when click change button is clicked chenge the mediaplayer view to image view. view changed but mediaplayer not stop i am using the following code

```
 change.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mediaplayer1.onPlayingStop1();
            Mainlayout.removeView(mediaplayer1);
            mediaplayer1= null;
        }
    });`

public void onPlayingStop1(){
       if (mp1.isPlaying()==true||mp1!=null) {
           try{
             System.out.println("Player outer Realsed");
             plsong.clear();
             mp1.stop();
             mp1.release();
             System.out.println("Player outer Realsed");

           } catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Exception"+e); 
             }
         }
   }
```

Comment: mp1.isPlaying() itself return true or false no need to write mp1.isPlaying()==true.

Comment: ok thanks..coditions are working fine..bur mediaplayer not stop when i change the view

Comment: Don't think this will solve your problem. But, you need to change the order of booleans in your if-statement. And, the OR should be an AND. Like: `if (mp1 != null && mp1.isPlaying())`.

Comment: @J.R.P r u swapping between play and pause button?If yes then don't remove views just control the visibility of views.(VISIBLE,GONE)

Comment: No Pratik. it's a two different views one is mediaplayer view..it's have a seekbar,play and pause controls. anthoer views is totally different it's have image and text..i used 2 views one linearlayout

Comment: use this condition if(mp1.isPlaying()){mp1.pause();} @J.R.P

Comment: This is not working any idea?

Answer (score 1):

hi i think you are not deallocating the media player

try deallocating it and override pause function

```
public void onPlayingStop1(){
       if (mp1.isPlaying()==true||mp1!=null) {
           try{
             System.out.println("Player outer Realsed");
             plsong.clear();
             mp1.pause();
             mp1.release();
             System.out.println("Player outer Realsed");

           } catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Exception"+e); 
             }
         }
   }
@Override
    onPause() {
    mp1.release();
    super.onPause();
}
```